# How do I save a user-defined function so that it can be used in all documents in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I created a UDF to convert a number to base32.  I would like to save this function (and any others I happen to create) so that I can use it in any future spreadsheets I make, not just the one it is saved in.  This is excel 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

save the file containing your udf as an addin (File/save as/addin (xla) ), then add a reference to it (tools/addins/browse to your file)